# How do I do make the object onscreen, move diagonally and repeatedly without an end?

Tags: html

```html
<svg width="1000" height="250">
  <rect width="150" height="150" fill="orange">
    <animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="300" dur="3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="2"/> 
  </rect>
</svg>
```

How to animate the rectangle to move diagonally?
Another query, how do I make the rectangle move repeatedly (no count)?
Thanks to however is able to answer this question.

Comment: Please answer this as soon as, and if possible, as this is for a school project.                                                                                                            
Thank You! ☺

Comment: can you not just copy that line and replace x with y

Comment: Azsgy, that doesn't seem to work.
Anyways, Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use repeatCount="indefinite" like this:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="250">
  <rect width="150" height="150" fill="orange" x="140">
    <animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="100%" dur="3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate> 
  </rect>
</svg>
```